# phpのfile_get_contents関数をPHPのcurl関数で書き変えたい

Tags: php, php-curl

file_get_contents関数を使って書かれたコードをPHPのcurl関数で書き変えているのですが,

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'access_token'
```

というメッセージが出てtwitterのtweetを取得できません。解決方法が分かる方、回答をお願いします。

全体のコードのリンクです。
https://github.com/sizaki30/TwitterAppOAuth/blob/master/TwitterAppOAuth.php

この方のサイトを参考にtweetを取得するサイトを作っています。
[Twitter API search/tweets で 100件以上のツイートを取得する（PHP）](https://blog.apar.jp/php/3007/)

curlについて参考にしたサイトです。
[phpでfile_get_contentsからcurlに移行する - Qiita](https://qiita.com/Tamagoham119/items/0862d12743ddd8175d6d#%E7%A7%BB%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)
[APIなどにfile_get_contents()を使うのはオススメしない理由と代替案 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/shinkuFencer/items/d7546c8cbf3bbe86dab8)

```
private function _getBearerToken($consumer_key, $consumer_secret){
    $oauth2_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token';
    $token = base64_encode(urlencode($consumer_key) . ':' . urlencode($consumer_secret));

    $request = array(
        'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'
    );
    $header = [
        'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization: Basic ' . $token,
    ];

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $oauth2_url); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($request));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

    $response_arr = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $response_arr['access_token'];//ここでWarning:が出る
    }

    public function get($api, $params = array())
    {
        $api_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/' . $api . '.json';

        if ($params) {
            $request = http_build_query($params, '', '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);
            $api_url .= '?' . $request;
        }

        $header = [
          'Authorization: Bearer ' . $this->_bearer_token,
        ];
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($request));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

        $response_json = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return $response_json;
    }
```

Comment: PHPの`file_get_contents()`で行っている処理(リクエスト)を、代わりにcurlコマンドで実行する場合にどんな引数(オプション)を指定すればよいか？という事でしょうか。

Comment: curlコマンドなんですか? PHPのcurl関数ではなく?

Comment: curlコマンドとPHPのcurl関数の区別がついていませんでした。今回はPHPのcurl関数を使いたいです。混乱させてすいません。

Comment: 質問は後からでも [編集] できるので、タイトルや本文の内容がより伝わりやすいように直接書き換えてみてください。

Comment: 質問を書き変えました。ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Comment: これなど参考になるのでは？ [phpでfile_get_contentsからcurlに移行する](https://qiita.com/Tamagoham119/items/0862d12743ddd8175d6d)

Comment: そこはチェックしたのですが上手くいきませんでした。

Comment: 内容が相応しいか不明ですが、こんなのも。[PHP で Twitter API OAuth 認証 「タイムライン取得」「つぶやき投稿」](https://wepicks.net/twitterapiv11_webapp/), [PHP ライブラリに頼らないTwitterAPI入門](https://qiita.com/mpyw/items/b59d3ce03f08be126000)

Comment: @空手バカボン 自身で試したこと、参考にした資料などがもしあれば、予め質問文に記載しておいてもらうとお互いに不要なやり取りを減らせると思いますので参考までに。

Comment: kunifさん情報ありがとうございます。参考にさせていただきます。

Comment: 参考にしたサイトを質問文に書き加えました。

Answer (score 1):

こんな感じではいかがでしょうか？
SSLの認証でエラーが出る場合があるので`CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`を`false`にしておくことをお勧めします。

```
$request = array(
        'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'
    );
$header = [
    'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
    'Authorization: Basic ' . $token,
];


$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $oauth2_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($request));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

$response_json = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。一歩進むことが出来ました。もう少しで解決できそうです。

Comment: 頂いたアドバイスをもとに質問を書き変えました。